# Trouble installing Ruby 2.0.0-p247 via RVM (OSX Mountain Lion)

Tags: ruby, rvm, osx-mountain-lion

My ultimate goal is to install the current version of Ruby on Rails. I am running on OS X Mountain Lion. Here's my process so far:

Installed RVM

```
$ \curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
```

Checked for known (and I assume approved) installs

```
$ rvm list known
```

I see that the current stable build is available

```
[ruby-]2.0.0[-p247]
```

Key in command to install

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0-p247
```

Note: I also tried these install commands

```
$ rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247
$ rvm install ruby=2.0.0-p247
```

I'm getting nowhere fast. Results:

```
$ rvm install 2.0.0-p247
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p247.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Certificates in '/usr/local/etc/openssl/cert.pem' already are up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #downloading ruby-2.0.0-p247, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #extracted to /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p247 (already extracted)
ruby-2.0.0-p247 - #configuring........
Error running './configure --prefix=/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared',
please read /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p247/1375141206_configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

I also ran this command in debug mode. To avoid clutter, you can access it [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/16vrJFA3akPJ5ZYLhwZefNMFSxuGUoEH1pxxAIze_qII/edit?usp=sharing).

Also, here is the log:

```
./configure
current path: /Users/xxxxx/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p247
command(7): ./configure --prefix=/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247 --with-opt-dir=/usr/local/opt/libyaml:/usr/local/opt/readline:/usr/local/opt/libksba:/usr/local/opt/openssl --disable-install-doc --without-tcl --without-tk --enable-shared
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --without-tcl, --without-tk
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.1
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p247':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

This is my first installation via RVM. $rvm list returns no gems.

Please ask if any additional information might be helpful.

**Edit** - [HERE](http://bit.ly/16wGvAk) is the log in case that might help anyone.

Comment: Trying to start my whole process again from scratch. Reinstalling Xcode & Commandline Tools now - then I'll try again. I will post my results when available.

Comment: please add `/Users/xxxxx/.rvm/src/ruby-2.0.0-p247/config.log`

Comment: I figured out the issue (kind of). Would it still be helpful to others if I post the log?

Comment: the log was of no help - go ahead and accept your answer

Comment: It might be worth trying [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv). I used to use RVM but had too many problems with it like this, so switching ended up being worth the trouble.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something must have been wrong with either my Xcode or my Command Line Tools install. Reinstalling both made everything run beautifully.

Comment: Downvote for lack of technical depth in your answer and recommending such an inefficient process.

Answer (score 3):

**For those that arrived here from google when you applied the same error as the query:**

I got this same problem but did not want to go through the ridiculously long process of reinstalling xcode like the accepted answer suggested. All I did was run 
`rvm get stable` And then run 
`rvm install ruby-2.0.0-p247` again
my original problem

[image: problem]
then after I ran
 
`rvm get stable`
[image: Solution]

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you install command line tool within XCode because it does not do it automatically (yes, I agree, command line tool should be installed by default) but it isn't.

Install XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> "Command Line Tool"

EDIT* missed the whole "made everything run beautifully part" and typed this all out-

Cheers, glad everything worked out!